# knex.js - debug only SQL

Tags: express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Is there any way to display only SQL queries on console when debugging mode is on?
I want to reduce the amount of informations which is displayed.

Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: See https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/167

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096957/how-can-i-view-the-query-knex-builds/70488259#70488259

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, if you're using MySQL, you can set

```
debug: ['ComQueryPacket']
```

as part of the config settings for mysql (not Knex).

I'll looking into adding this as an option in Knex though.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 52):

Set environment variables to configure the `debug` module:

- `DEBUG=knex:query` for just queries
- `DEBUG=knex:tx` for transactions
- and `DEBUG=knex*` for everything.

Comment: after setting env then how to debug while running app?

Comment: Much better answer than the one accepted or the other one where you need to register function that logs queries. Works really well!

Answer (score 22):

If what you need is to show the query string, one way is to register a function that logs the query data using the event 'query' that Knex emit just before executing the query.

For example:

```
var knex = require( 'knex' );
knex.on( 'query', function( queryData ) {
    console.log( queryData );
});
```

After that, before every query, the anonymous function is called and queryData contains json with the information about the query.

Comment: I did this, but I got `TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.

Comment: This can be shortened to `knex.on('query', console.log)`.