# How can I view the query `knex` builds?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

For debugging purposes, I want to see the SQL query `knex` is executing. For example, I want to view SQL that `knex` produces for this code:

```
 knex('statistics')
    .del()
    .where({
        'stats': 'reddit',
    });
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

https://knexjs.org/guide/interfaces.html#other

```
knex('statistics')
    .del()
    .where({
        'stats': 'reddit',
    }).toSQL().toNative()
```

Comment: To get query string is `toNative().sql`

Comment: And to get parameter bindings for that query is `toNative().bindings`

Comment: This does not return the SQL command as a string, it returns an object. To get the raw SQL as a string, you want `.toString()` or `.toQuery()` (see my answer as it is more comprehensive)

Comment: @JeremyBernier No... if you call `.toString()` / `.toQuery()` that is not the query that knex runs when the builder is triggered. Outputted string might be working SQL some times and sometimes it is not. Knex does not do value escaping correctly in every case when rendering string from builder. `.toQuery()` and `.toString()` are aliases to each other. Both should be used only for debugging. `.toSQL().toNative()` returns the templated SQL query string for the used dialect and corresponding bindings. That should be the exact query that is executed by the knex when the builder is triggered.

Comment: Link is broken. Now both toString() and toNative() are documented in http://knexjs.org/guide/interfaces.html#other. They both seem to be good for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 21):

```
knex('statistics')
    .del()
    .where({
        'stats': 'reddit',
    }).toString();
```

Comment: I do not think this an improvement over the accepted answer.

Comment: Guys, I tried to find the way to get raw SQL. `toString()` is the same way as `.toSQL().toNative()` but shorter. Do you really think that there is one right answer only?

Comment: This works in knex 0.21

Comment: @greybeard I think it is an improvement

Comment: This gave me raw SQL that I could copy and paste and run without any changes in the database. `.toSQL().toNative()` gave me something for JavaScript that I could not run directly in the database.

Answer (score 17):

`.toString()` and `.toQuery()` return the full SQL query as a string

For your example:

```
knex('statistics')
    .del()
    .where({
        'stats': 'reddit',
    }).toString();
```

returns:

```
delete from "statistics" where "stats" = 'reddit'
```

Whereas `.toSQL().toNative()` returns an object:

```
knex('statistics')
    .del()
    .where({
        'stats': 'reddit',
    }).toSQL().toNative();
```

```
{
  sql: 'select * from "books" where "author" = $1',
  bindings: [ 'John Doe' ]
}
```

Comment: Not clear which things the OP wanted, but it's super useful to have these options laid out.

Answer (score 6):

To print all queries then passing a `debug: true` flag on your initialization object will turn on `debugging` for all queries.

```
knex({
    client: 'mysql',
    debug: true,
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: ''
    }
})
```

Ref:https://knexjs.org/#Installation-debug

Answer (score 3):

you can use `toKnexQuery().toSQL()`

```
console.log(query.toKnexQuery().toSQL())
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case toSQL()... does not produce the "parsed" SQL string, only toString() works, I'm not sure if this depends on one's specific usage of the Query Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I see everybody writing to use ".toSQL().toNative()" or ".toQuery()" without explaining the difference so here we go.

- `toSQL().toNative()`: copying from the documentation, "*outputs **object** with sql string and bindings in a dialects format in the same way that knex internally sends them to underlying DB driver*".
- `toQuery()`: returns a **string** replacing the bindings. This is what I use the most to run the query manually in the DB driver because for larger queries is a pain to replace each binding without a typo or replacing the wrong binding.

For example:

```
    const queryBuilder = knex().select().from('foo').where('bar', '=', 'baz');

// {
//   sql: 'select * from "foo" where "bar" = $1',
//   bindings: [
//     'baz'
//   ]
// }
console.log(queryBuilder.toSql().toNative();

// select * from "foo" where "bar" = 'baz' 
console.log(queryBuilder.toQuery());
```