# Knex: what's the function to ORDERBY for each WHERE condition in a SELECT statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, knex.js

I'm querying a database using knex, and I need the results to be ordered in a specific way.
Currently, I have the following code which returns all the results I want, albeit in a haphazard order.

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderBy("FruitTag")
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderBy("FruitTag")
  .distinct()
```

I want it to order each whereLike query alphabetically, and then essentially concatenate the three whereLike queries together.

E.g.

```
AtoZ: whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
AtoZ: orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
AtoZ: orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
```

I tried reordering the orderBy but it seems to still return the results in not the order I want

**EDIT 1:**
Given the following table below:

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | apple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | james | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ppab123 | ppapple | wherelike1 satisfies |

When I execute the query with ${query} as "pp", it should return in the following order:

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppab123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | james | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

You can notice that it first orders the results by the whereLike condition, then alphabatically based on conditions (e.g. wherelike1 will orderBy FruitTag, wherelike2 will orderBy FruitName, wherelike3 orderBy FruitTag

**EDIT 2:**
Using the current suggested answer (credits to @Barmar):

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderByRaw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`]))
  .distinct()
```

I get the result:

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

Is there a way to additionally order each orderByRaw by FruitName alphabatically again to get the following result?

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

**EDIT 3:**
Using the current suggested answer (credits to @Barmar):

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderByRaw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .distinct()
```

Expected result

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

Actual result

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |

Although now the FruitName is indeed additionally sorted, using this code apparently switched the order of orderByRaw(wherelike2) and orderByRaw(wherelike3) which messes up everything again

**EDIT 4:**
Code used:

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderByRaw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .distinct()
```

Raw SQL:

```
"select `FruitTag`, `FruitName`, `FruitDescription` from `FRUITTBL` where `FruitTag` like 'pp%' or `FruitName` like 'pp%' or `FruitTag` like '%pp%' order by FruitTag LIKE 'pp%' DESC, `FruitName` asc, FruitName LIKE 'pp%' DESC, FruitTag LIKE '%pp%' DESC, `FruitName` asc limit 20"
```

Expected Table

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

Actual Table

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |

**EDIT 5:**
Almost perfect again, it's the same code and problem as EDIT 3, but this time I've added the rawSQL for easy troubleshooting

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderByRaw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`]))
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .distinct()
```

Raw SQL:

```
"select `FruitTag`, `FruitName`, `FruitDescription` 
from `FRUITTBL` 
where `FruitTag` like 'pp%' or `FruitName` like 'pp%' or `FruitTag` like '%pp%' 
order by FruitTag LIKE 'pp%' DESC, 
        `FruitName` asc, 
        FruitName LIKE 'pp%' DESC, 
        `FruitName` asc, 
        FruitTag LIKE '%pp%' DESC, 
        `FruitName` asc 
limit 20"
```

Expected result

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |

Actual result

| FruitTag | FruitName | FruitDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ppaa123 | aapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | abpple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ppaa123 | ppaapple | wherelike1 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jaames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| ahousepp | jbames | wherelike3 satisfies |
| bhousepp | tyler | wherelike3 satisfies |
| fipptruck | ppaineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |
| firetruck2 | ppbineapple | wherelike2 satisfies |

This code apparently switched the orderByRaw(wherelike2) results and orderByRaw(wherelike3) results

Comment: When you have multiple ordering columns, it orders by the first one. The second is used for ordering within groups where the first column is the same, and the next is used when the first 2 are the same, and so on.

Comment: Can you show an example of the ordering that you want?

Comment: @Barmar I've edited the question with an example at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `knex.raw()` to order by a comparison expression.

```
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`])
  .orderByRaw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`])
  .orderByRaw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`])
  .orderBy("FruitName")
  .distinct()
```

The value of a `LIKE` condition is 1 when it's true, 0 when false, so ordering by the condition DESC puts the rows where the condition matches first.

Comment: it currently gives 'sql error' when executed, i'm looking through to see what's wrong

Comment: I don't use knex.js myself, I assumed you could use `knex.raw()` there in `orderBy()`. You might need to use `orderByRaw()`.

Comment: I've tried editing the obvious typos, but it still gives 'sql error'
knex("FRUITTBL")
  .select("FruitTag", "FruitName", "FruitDescription")
  .whereLike("FruitTag", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitName", `${query}%`)
  .orWhereLike("FruitTag", `%${query}%`)
  .limit(20)
  .offset(`${page}`)
  .orderBy(knex.raw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy(knex.raw('FruitName LIKE ? DESC', [`${query}%`]))
  .orderBy(knex.raw('FruitTag LIKE ? DESC', [`%${query}%`]))
  .distinct()

Comment: Can you print out the resulting SQL? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096957/how-can-i-view-the-query-knex-builds

Comment: Is it possible to further sort each orderByRaw by FruitName again? I've edited the question with an example of what I mean

Comment: You should be able to insert `.orderBy('columnName')` between the `orderByRaw()` calls, like in my answer.

Comment: Does not work, adding .orderBy() after the .orderByRaw() calls messes things up, I've edited the question with the table it returned

Comment: Can you show the SQL?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I thought you wanted to order by the column that was selected, not always by FruitName

Comment: I've updated the question with the Code used, Raw SQL.toString(), Expected Table, Actual Table

Comment: You're missing one of the `orderBy("FruitName")`

Comment: Even if I add that it doesn't work, the middle one should not matter right? Since the middle one is already sorting FruitName Descending

Comment: No, it's sorting by whether or not FruitName matches the pattern.

Comment: I've added the FruitNames again and now it's back to the same code as earlier (EDIT 3), this time I've added the raw SQL to help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong now, I'm reading it again and again to check for any typos and it seems correct. Unless you are not allowed to use orderBy and orderByRaw together?

Comment: Figured it out. The `orderBy("FruitName")`  should just be once, at the end.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your efforts! I've marked your answer as the solution