# inserting a list of entries into sqlite using knex on expressJS with unique field constraint

Tags: javascript, express, sqlite, knex.js, node-sqlite3

I am trying to insert a list of exercises into sqlite DB. The app is on express JS and I am using `sqlite3` and `knex` to interact with the DB. I am trying to add a list of exercises into the table `exercisesDB`, but only if the name of exercise doesn't already exist in the table using knex transaction:

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
      for (const exercise of exercisesToAdd) {
        await trx('exercisesDB').insert(exercise).onConflict('name').ignore() 
      }
    })
```

But I get an error
[Error: insert into `exercisesDB` [data] on conflict (`name`) do nothing - SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: exercisesDB.id]

Seems that `knex` is checking `id` constraint (which I am not passing in the `exercisesToAdd` list) instead of `name` constraint

Could it be a knex problem?

I tried adding then catch to trx so that the code looked like:

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
  exercisesToAdd.forEach(
        (exercise) => await trx('exercisesDB').insert(exercise).onConflict('name').ignore().then(trx.commit).catch(trx.rollback)
      )
    })
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#onconflict) claims that this should work.

Comment: Can you `.toSQL().toNative()` to show the query that it creates? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096957/how-can-i-view-the-query-knex-builds

Comment: What is the id of a new record supposed to be if you're not passing it in? Is there a trigger? Typically ids are not nullable which means you're attempting to create records with null ids.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `name` column already have a `UNIQUE` constraint on it? If not, you need to add that to the DB schema before this will work.

See the knex.js docs [here](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#onconflict):

> For PostgreSQL and SQLite, the column(s) specified by this method must either be the table's PRIMARY KEY or have a UNIQUE index on them, or the query will fail to execute. When specifying multiple columns, they must be a composite PRIMARY KEY or have composite UNIQUE index.

Seems like it would check the PK by default otherwise...